Adjusting elements width while resizing flexbox
I'm trying to resize the elements in a flexbox. My requirement is that, When I am resizing the left side outer box, I want the azure colored one to adjust rather than the orange one getting overflowed as shown in the below figure. By adjusting the azure box, I mean the content in the azure box can be cutoff or can be with ellipsis overflow. 
Please run the following code snippet to see the implementation.


.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: beige;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}

.inner-child1 {
  flex-basis: 0%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: azure;
}

.inner-child2 {
  background-color: bisque;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="inner-child1 inner">
      <div>child1 ---------------</div>
      <div>child2 ---------------</div>
      <div>child3 ---------------</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-child2 inner">
      <div>child4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">outer</div>
</div>




https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ExBVgxa
